# strtotime failing with too much seconds precision

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Too much seconds precision causes `strtotime` to fail when the input is a ISO 8601 datetime string. Is there a way around this in PHP?

```
strtotime('2017-10-11T22:49:52.123456789Z'); //returns false
```

Comment: Do you need such accuracy in your PHP code?

Comment: If you're able to alter the string to reduce it to millisecond accuracy, then `new DateTime('2017-10-11T22:49:52.123Z')` produces a valid object

Answer (score 1):

The smallest entity with `strtotime` is a second. If this is ok as a result just do it like so:

```
$str  = '2017-10-11T22:49:52.123456789Z';
$time = strtotime(substr($str, 0, 19));
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str  = '2017-10-11T22:49:52.123456789Z';
$split = explode(".", $str);
$time = strtotime($split[0]); #2017-10-11T22:49:52
echo $time; #1507751392
```

This is the way you get it :)
I hope its helps you.

**EDITED**

And this is a better way than using explode.

```
$str  = '2017-10-11T22:49:52.123456789Z';
$time = strtotime(substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '.')));
echo $time; #1507751392
```

Comment: Note: this works for this format but fails if you get a date string without a dot.

Comment: Yes, it would, so its better to use `strtok` with it, `$time = strtotime(strtok($str, '.'));`. Thank you @NickZinger.